# Understanding the case $\alpha < 0$ in thm. (5) page 75 in Royden "Fourth Edition".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The theorem and part of its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

My question is:

In case of the proof in the case $\alpha < 0$: How is the proof related to our previous knowledge that $\inf A = -\sup (-A)$, could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the facts $\inf A = - \sup(-A)$ and $\sup \lambda A  = \lambda \sup A$ where $\lambda A := \{\lambda a: a \in A\}$ and $-A := (-1)A$, we have

$$\inf_{\varphi \geqslant \alpha f}\int_E \varphi = \inf_{[\varphi/\alpha] \leqslant  f}\alpha \int_E [\varphi/\alpha] = - \sup_{[\varphi/\alpha] \leqslant  f}(-\alpha)\int_E [\varphi/\alpha] = -(-\alpha)\sup_{[\varphi/\alpha] \leqslant f}\int_E [\varphi/\alpha] \\= \alpha \sup_{[\varphi/\alpha] \leqslant f}\int_E [\varphi/\alpha]$$

Here we use $ -\alpha > 0$ and $ \varphi \geqslant \alpha f \implies \varphi/\alpha \leqslant f$ when $\alpha < 0$.

Comment: :) Thank you so much! explained in a very precise way

Comment: @Smart: You’re welcome.