# Understanding the case $\alpha = \beta =1 $ in thm. (5) page 75 in Royden "Fourth Edition".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The theorem and part of its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

My question is:

In the second paragraph, are they taking the infimum of the inequality in the first paragraph and because the left-hand side is already a number (the infimum) then the right-hand side is the only that is affected by taking the infimum? could anyone help me in answering this question , please?

Comment: You have something like $a \le \int \psi_1+\int \psi_2$. Then $a \le  \inf_{f \le \psi_1} \psi_1+  \inf_{f \le \psi_2} \int \psi_2 = \int f + \int g$.

Comment: Do you have brackets after the first inf after the first inequality? @copper.hat

Comment: I think you corrected it thanks! @copper.hat

Comment: Could you please look at this also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398117/understanding-the-case-alpha-0-in-thm-5-page-75-in-royden-fourth-editio (if you have time)? @copper.hat

Answer (score 1):

The inequality 
$$
\int_E(f+g)\le \int_E\psi_1+\int_E\psi_2
$$
is true for all simple functions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ with $f\le \psi_1$ and $g\le \psi_2$. Taking infimum among all such $\psi_1$ on both sides and then the infimum among all the $\psi_2$ gives
$$
\int_E(f+g)\le \inf_{f\le\psi_1,\psi_1\text{simple}}\int_E\psi_1
+\inf_{f\le\psi_2,\psi_2\text{simple}}\int_E\psi_2=\int_Ef+\int_Eg.
$$